# How to select a given column from a line of text?

Tags: unix, shell, sh

Suppose I have this sentence:

```
My name is bob.
```

And I want to copy the word "is" from that sentence into a variable. How would I access that word, without knowing in advance the word I am looking for? If I know a specific word or string is in the third column of text in a five column text line, how can I take the word in the third column?

I'm using the bourne shell.

Comment: Take a look at sed and awk to do this kind of processing.

Answer (score 20):

```
word=$(cut -d ' ' -f 3 filename)
```

`cut` gives us the third field of each line (in this case there's 1).  `-d` is used to specify space as a delimiter.  `$()` captures the output, then we assign it to the `word` variable.

Comment: I don't believe tail is required from what the OP meant, the leading line of numbers (now removed) was spaced out to indicate columns rather than being content.

Answer (score 13):

you can use either `cut`, `awk`, etc.

Example:

```
awk '{print $3}' my_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence='My name is bob.'
set -- $sentence
echo $3
```

or

```
sentence='My name is bob.'
set -- $sentence
shift 2    # or use a variable
echo $1
```